# Finding the expiration date of a domain?

Tags: domains, whois

Is there a way to find the expiration date of a ".id.au" domain?
I can't seem to find any information on any .id.au domain I search on.

Comment: Have you tried doing a whois? Can you give us a sample URL?

Comment: Sure - id.au is meant for people (http://www.ausregistry.com.au/id.php) - so try things like "smith.id.au"

Answer (score 5):

`whois.audns.net.au`, the WHOIS server for `.au` domains, [doesn't support the expiration date information](http://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/v1.3.10/lib/whois/answer/parser/whois.audns.net.au.rb#L60).

Even the [public WHOIS](http://www.mywebname.com.au/) hides this information.

Comment: Interesting - so is the only way to find this information by contacting the registry?

Comment: Yes, assuming they will disclose it to you.

Comment: first sign up at crazydomains.com.au then search domian you can back Order by pay money

Answer (score 2):

I did a `whois` search on `bob.id.au` and it seems like the `id.au` domain names don't show expiration in their `whois` records.  This may be a cool way to do things and prevent spam.

I would contact a registrar that handles these by phone to get more insight.